# Multiple image names

Tags: python-3.x

I need to save images after cropping that image in a for loop, how can this be achieved?

I have tried using `img2.save("img"+i+".png")` but this gives an error.

```
for file in files(path):
            if file.endswith('.png'):
                img=Image.open(file)
                img2 = img.crop((x0,y0,x1,y1))
                img2.save("img"+i+".png")
                i+=1
```

The output should be as follows:
1. image1_crop.png
2. image2_crop.png
....

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to post the exact error message but you obviously have a TypeError here:

```
img2.save("img"+i+".png")
```

since adding strings and numbers is not allowed (for the obvious reason that it makes no sense at all).

You want to use string formating instead:

```
            img2.save("img{}.png".format(i))
```